# Appy overflow in Container widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to design a `Container` as displayed in the center, below.

[image]

Here is my code for doing so:

```
Container(
   width: 48,
   height: 48,
   decoration: SideBarStyles.recentItem,
   child: Image.network(
     'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
     fit: BoxFit.cover,
   ),
),
```

**SideBarStyles.recentItem** value

```
  static BoxDecoration recentItem = BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
    color: Color.fromRGBO(42, 37, 82, 0.15),
    border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Variables.sideBarColorDark)
  );
```

The problem is image is floating out of the box as:

[image]

How do I hide the overflow of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres and example

```
 Container(
                      width: 48,
                      height: 48,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Variables.sideBarColorDark),
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                          image: new NetworkImage(
                            'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is like this.

```
Container(
   width: 48,
   height: 48,
   decoration: SideBarStyles.recentItem,
),
```

And `decoration` like this.

```
  static BoxDecoration recentItem = BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
    color: Color.fromRGBO(42, 37, 82, 0.15),
    border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Variables.sideBarColorDark)
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any'),
    ),
  );
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `container` corners to be cropped/rounded either set the `borderRadius` property in the `container` to `BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(value))`. Or wrap the `container` in a `ClipRRect` widget and set the `borderRadius` property to `BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(value))`.